# How to Reference Template of Control within ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to style the DateTimePicker from the Extended WPF Toolkit a bit differntly, especially the Calendar control.

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="DatePickerTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
           ...
    <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calendar" Template="{StaticResource CalendarTemplate}" BorderThickness="0" DisplayDate="2014-05-14"/>"
           ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

What is necessary so that I am allowed to reference the Control template below in the code above (both are in the same file)?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate" TargetType="Calendar">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <CalendarItem x:Name="CalendarItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Template="{StaticResource CalendarItemTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

At present VS complains: The ressource "CalendarTemplate" could not be resolved.

**Update:**
After changing the order of definitions, so first define   `<ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate" TargetType="Calendar">...`
then the ControlTemplate that uses `CalendarTemplate` it works, remembers me of c++, but now I get the following Exception if I try to open the calendarcontrol:

```
Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' threw an exception.
```

Comment: Is there an InnerException for the "Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' threw an exception." you are seeing? It could be that you have the same x:Key being declared more than once...

Comment: no it says: key can not be null

Comment: Then you must be declaring a ControlTemplate or some other type in your Resources section and not setting x:Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a StaticResource so you should be declaring your CalendarTemplate as it's **x:Key** not it's x:Name i.e.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate" TargetType="Calendar">
...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Update to show something similar working (note that these are defined at the same level in my Xaml file i.e. both directly under my main Views Resources)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ABC123" TargetType="Button">

</ControlTemplate>

<!-- creating a control template for TextBox -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PasswordBoxTemplateBase" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="root" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
        <Border x:Name="normalBorder"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
            <Button Template="{StaticResource ABC123}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: my appologies, error while coping, updated the question, in the real code i use x:key not x:Name

Comment: @lsteinme are you still seeing the issue?

Comment: yes I still have the issue, the mistake with name/key happend while copying

Comment: @Isteinme are there any other build errors you are seeing? I currently have a single Xaml file with 2 ControlTemplates defined (I will add it into my answer to make it easier to read) and it is building and running fine

Comment: no, not any build errors, the only thing I noticed now is that if I change the order of declaration so that <ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate" TargetType="Calendar"> comes first and <ControlTemplate  x:Key="DatePickerTemplate" comes second in code, at least there is no complain anymore about that it doesn't find the template, but now it complains something else, will edit the question

Comment: Marked as anwers, because the orginal problem was because of the wrong order

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of the **x:Name** on a StaticResource rather than an **x:Key**. It should be like this (***x:Key="CalendarTemplate"***):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate" TargetType="Calendar">
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate  x:Key="DatePickerTemplate" TargetType="DatePicker">
   <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calendar" Template="{StaticResource CalendarTemplate}" BorderThickness="0"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: mistake while retyping the code, already corrected in the question